# F# actually compiles private members as internal in IL. Bug?

Tags: .net, f#

I always assumed that the access control keywords in F# (`public`, `private`, `internal`) work in the same way as they do in C#.  Indeed from the MSDN documentation [Access Control (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233188.aspx):

> - **public** indicates that the entity can be accessed by all callers.
> - **internal** indicates that the entity can be accessed only from the same assembly.
> - **private** indicates that the entity can be accessed only from the enclosing type or module.

This seems to be pretty consistent with my assumption and also multiple answers on the topic provided here at SO.

However, when I poked into the compiled code with Reflector, I discovered that all those members declared as *private* are actually compiled as *internal* (assembly visibility), which is not matching the documentation.

To avoid any doubt, I have created as small test to confirm this.

**F# code:**

```
// Make internals visible to other assemblies
[<assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyCSharpAssembly")>]


// OK. Expect: "internal static class PrivateModule" in C#
module private PrivateModule =

    // FAIL. Expect: "private static void privateStaticMethod()" in C#
    let private privateStaticMethod() = ignore()

// OK. Expect: "internal class InternalClass" in C#
type private InternalClass() =

    // FAIL. Expect: "private int privateInstanceField" in C#
    let privateInstanceField = 0

    // FAIL. Expect: "private static int privateStaticField" in C#
    static let privateStaticField = 0

    // FAIL. Expect: "private int privateInstanceMethod()" in C#
    let privateInstanceMethod() = privateInstanceField

    // FAIL. Expect: "private in PrivateInstanceMember()" in C#
    member private this.PrivateInstanceMember() = privateInstanceField

    // OK. Expect: "internal int InternalInstanceMember" in C#
    member internal this.InternalInstanceMember() = privateStaticField
```

I have put together a bit of C# code to make sure I'm not imagining things.

**C# test code**, and everything compiles.

```
public class TestVisibility
{
    // This is a demo to verify that the members are indeed
    // internal (assembly) and can be accessed from C# if the
    // F# assembly is compiled with [<assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("C# assembly")>]
    public void Run()
    {
        // All of these compile.
        PrivateModule.privateStaticMethod();

        InternalClass x = new InternalClass();

        int a = InternalClass.privateStaticField;
        var b = x.InternalInstanceMember();
        var c = x.PrivateInstanceMember();
        var d = x.privateInstanceField;
        var f = x.privateInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

I used VS2012, targeting .NET 4.0, all settings are default. Tried both Debug and release modes with same results.

**Question**: What is actual expected behaviour as per design? Is it a bug? Or I am doing something wrong?

**Suggestion**: If this is intended behaviour, perhaps it might be a good idea to explicitly mention this in documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [F# 3.0 specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818992): *The CLI compiled form of all non-public entities is **internal**.*

Comment: Hmm that does seem like a spec bug, as above that it says says internal fields can be accessed by assemblys listed in InternalsVisibleTo, but that private fields are only accessed by the enclosing type. Compiling everything at the CLI to level internals those statements are no longer true.